# Angular $http cache for multiple browser tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, angular-http, cachefactory

I want to cache `get` requests using angular `$http` service. `$http` service uses `$cacheFactory` for caching.

Can we use angular `$http` service for caching data of multiple browser tabs? I mean does the cache have a cookie like persistent behaviour?

Comment: It is stored in memory, so no cookie-like behaviour. But maybe you can implement one with localstorage

Comment: @karaxuna So the $http service also doesn't have a persistent behaviour. Has it?

Comment: You know that the browser itself caches GET requests, do you? So it's not exactly clear what you need.

Comment: Any service can use the $cacheFactory. The Documentation -- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$cacheFactory.Cache

Comment: @SampathLiyanage in angular, when navigating, page does not reload, so data in cache factory IS persistent unless you reload a page.

Comment: @SampathLiyanage, did you get any resolution? if yes, please share it as correct answer.